# Encode::Locale fails 3/13 tests of env.t in Cygwin

Tags: perl, cygwin

I'm having trouble installing `Encode::Locale` in Cygwin (v1.7.35, 64-bit version) and getting errors about it failing tests in `t/env.t`.

```
$ cpan install Encode::Locale
Going to read '/home/agrajag9/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Mon, 23 Mar 2015 12:17:02 GMT
Running install for module 'Encode::Locale'
Running make for G/GA/GAAS/Encode-Locale-1.04.tar.gz
Checksum for /home/agrajag9/.cpan/sources/authors/id/G/GA/GAAS/Encode-Locale-1.04.tar.gz ok

  CPAN.pm: Going to build G/GA/GAAS/Encode-Locale-1.04.tar.gz

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Encode::Locale
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
cp lib/Encode/Locale.pm blib/lib/Encode/Locale.pm
Manifying 1 pod document
  GAAS/Encode-Locale-1.04.tar.gz
  make -- OK
Running make test
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/usr/bin/perl.exe" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/alias.t ...... ok
t/arg.t ........ # ENCODING_LOCALE is UTF-8
t/arg.t ........ ok
t/env.t ........ Failed 3/13 subtests
t/tain.t ....... ok
t/warn_once.t .. ok

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/arg.t      (Wstat: 0 Tests: 4 Failed: 0)
  TODO passed:   1-4
t/env.t      (Wstat: 0 Tests: 10 Failed: 0)
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 13 tests but ran 10.
Files=5, Tests=25,  2 wallclock secs ( 0.05 usr  0.19 sys +  0.29 cusr  0.68 csys =  1.21 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/5 test programs. 0/25 subtests failed.
Makefile:856: recipe for target 'test_dynamic' failed
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
  GAAS/Encode-Locale-1.04.tar.gz
  make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports GAAS/Encode-Locale-1.04.tar.gz
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
```

Manually copying the compiled version of `Encode/Locale.pm` to `/lib/perl5/5.14/` and running `env.t`:

```
$ perl t/env.t
1..13
ok 1 - env read
ok 2 - env write retval old value
ok 3 - env write worked
ok 4 - env affected %ENV
ok 5 - env write retval old value
ok 6 - env write worked
ok 7 - env write undef deletes from %ENV
ok 8 - env write retval encoded
ok 9 - env write worked
ok 10 - env affected %ENV
```

It appears that the following tests are failing:

```
is env("\x{20AC}", 1), undef, 'env write retval old value';
is env("\x{20AC}"), 1, 'env write worked';
is $ENV{"\x80"}, 1, 'env affected %ENV';
```

Output of `perl -v`

```
This is perl 5, version 14, subversion 4 (v5.14.4) built for cygwin-thread-multi
(with 14 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)

Copyright 1987-2013, Larry Wall

Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License or the
GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5 source kit.

Complete documentation for Perl, including FAQ lists, should be found on
this system using "man perl" or "perldoc perl".  If you have access to the
Internet, point your browser at http://www.perl.org/, the Perl Home Page.
```

Comment: Inside of `~/.cpan/build`, they'll be directories whose name starts with `Encode-Local`. Go into one of them, and type `perl -Mblib t/env.t`

Comment: `$ perl -Mblib t/env.t
1..13
ok 1 - env read
ok 2 - env write retval old value
ok 3 - env write worked
ok 4 - env affected %ENV
ok 5 - env write retval old value
ok 6 - env write worked
ok 7 - env write undef deletes from %ENV
ok 8 - env write retval encoded
ok 9 - env write worked
ok 10 - env affected %ENV`

No different from above.

Answer (score 2):

Setting an Cygwin environment variable with a name outside 7-bit ASCII causes a segmentation fault on every version of perl I use, and is also disallowed in python.

```
import os;
os.environ[chr(126)]="126"
print os.environ[chr(126)]
os.environ[chr(130)]="130"
print os.environ[chr(130)]

$ python env.py
126
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "env.py", line 4, in <module>
    os.environ[chr(130)]="130"
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 473, in __setitem__
    putenv(key, item)
OSError: [Errno 14] Bad address
```

Force install (`cpan -f Encode::Locale`) and don't sweat it. If you're not doing any dark magic, you don't need those fancy environment variable names.

(You can still set the environment variable *values* to just about anything, though.)

Comment: Wish i could vote this up twice.  It is always good to understand _why_ we are `force`ing something.